# Validation error on Postman though field inputs are given

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, api-design

Was making a RESTful API and was working as expected. I was using postman and mongodb, and made requests to work around.
But now only Delete and Get requests are working, Update and create requests are returning that these "fields are required" though they are not empty.
This was working fine until I added router.

```
const express = require("express");
require("./db/conn");
const Student = require("./models/students");
const studentRouter = require("./routers/stds");

// Environment Variables
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// Calling Router
app.use(studentRouter);

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Listening to port 
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Connection at ${port}`);
});
```

```
// Creating Router
const express = require("express");
const router = new express.Router();
const Student = require("../models/students");

// Creating URLs
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});

// Creating data
router.post("/students", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = new Student(req.body);
    const createUser = await user.save();
    console.log(createUser);
    res.status(201).send(createUser);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});

// Reading data
router.get("/students", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const studentsData = await Student.find();
    if (!studentsData) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    } else {
      res.send(studentsData);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
  }
});

// Reading data using IDs
router.get("/students/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const _id = await req.params.id;
    const studentData = await Student.find({ _id });
    res.send(studentData);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});

// Update Student's Data by ID
router.patch("/students/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const _id = req.params.id;
    const updateStudents = await Student.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id },
      req.body,
      {
        new: true
      });
    res.send(updateStudents);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});

// Delete Student's Data by I
router.delete("/students/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const deleteStudent = await Student.findByIdAndDelete({ id });
    if (!id) {
      return res.status(400).send();
    }
    else {
      res.send(deleteStudent);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
})

module.exports = router;
```

My Schema file.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");

const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: [true, "Already Exists"],
    validate(value) {
      if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid Email")
      }
    }
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    minlength: 10,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

// creating new collection using model
const Student = new mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);

module.exports = Student;
```

[Inputs are given but it doesn't takes it as one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIZPd.png)

Please ask if need more information...

Comment: What does it print when you `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: @JakeJackson No nothing is in the console :(

Comment: @JakeJackson I did `console.log(req.body)`  on update request, got undefined.

Comment: Could it be to do with the fact it's being sent as `raw` instead of as `JSON` on Postman?

Comment: Actually it was working perfectly moments before I added router and moved my requests from app.js to stds.js, also I guess it's being sent as JSON data.

Comment: @JakeJackson it is indeed JSON data being sent not raw, raw can pass several type of data and he indeed have selected JSON.

Comment: To be honest, it was just a shot in the dark. Since it was `undefined` I knew it would have to do with JSON, which was the case but for a different reason (your answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending data to your router without parsing it first.

```js
// Calling Router
app.use(studentRouter);

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
```

This should be other way around

```js
// Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Calling Router
app.use(studentRouter);
```